# What do you do when, in editing with MathJax, what you see in the preview is OK but the result is all messed up?

Tags: support, mathjax, editing, markdown-preview

I tried to edit [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3523881/875). When the preview looked OK, I saved the edit, but the actual outcome was a mess. I tried various workarounds, but each time the result, despite a good preview, was worse or introduced a new error. Finally, I tried to cancel all my edits and roll back to the OP's version, but (not really understanding how to do this) only created a labyrinth of newly numbered edits.

Luckily the final result is somewhat an improvement on the original, but it is only half way to being what I wanted. I dare not attempt a further edit for fear of making it worse again.

Comment: Looking at [revision 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/3523881/3) and it's [source code](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/b8f4d0ff-3d92-488f-920c-0ab42eac16b2/view-source), my guess is that the problem was most likely the unusual pairing of dollars in the form `$....$$$....$$`. (Instead of three dollars, you most likely intended to have there one dollar ending the previous group and two dollars starting the centered formula.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak : Thanks, that's very helpful.